# How does Pfizer justify it's Beta-Binomial model?

Tags: binomial-distribution, clinical-trials, beta-binomial-distribution

This is a bit of a hodge podge of different clinical trial related questions, but starting with some basics. It seems like they're defining vaccine efficacy differently depending on where you look. At one point they say:

$$VE = 1- IRR = 1-\frac{\text{confirmed cases in vaccinated group/1000 years}}{\text{confirmed cases in unvaccinated group/1000 years}}$$

Thus, under that definition, VE is a statistic that can be calculated from data. However, later they say:

$$\theta = \frac{1-VE}{2-VE} $$

And then they put a prior on $\theta$, implying that VE is not a statistic but actually a parameter in their model. Am I missing something, or are they just using VE in different ways in different places? How does their 'statistic' definition relate to their 'parameter' definition?

If I understand their model right, if $N_{vax}$ is the number of vaccinated patients who end up with Covid then:

$$N_{vax} \sim Binomial(170, \theta) $$

Where $\theta$ controls your probability of being from the vaccinated group. A couple questions about how they justify this model:

1. Even though in the earlier part of the paper they talk about cases per 1000 person years, they seem to just be using people counts here. Is that because they carefully controlled the amount of people in each group and the time under observation?
2. It seems that if people were in different risks (for example, one patient lived in a city w/high case counts and another lived in a city with very low), then saying their probability of being from the vaccine group as strictly controlled by $\theta$ would be inaccurate. Is there some kind of randomization argument they make that makes all the other risk factors ignorable?
3. Would there be anything wrong here with fitting a logistic regression and reporting an odds ratio? It seems like that would have the benefit of allowing them to incorporate time at risk, but what are the advantages of this model? Does it have something to do with controlling the Type 1 error rate using the Bayesian testing framework?

See study [here.](https://www.nejm.org/doi/suppl/10.1056/NEJMoa2034577/suppl_file/nejmoa2034577_protocol.pdf) Page 91 is where most of the confusion lies. They seem to make pretty clear that VE and IRR are calculated from data, yet also use VE as their parameter of interest in the hypothesis test.

Comment: Can you link to the source material? Web link/PDF? And with page numbers?

Comment: Updated @HeteroskedasticJim

Comment: So it's a large document. At the end of your paragraph where you go, "At one point, they say:", that could use a page number. Basically every reference to the document could use a page number. Readers would be much more likely to respond that way.

Comment: I wasn't looking for someone to read the document (I did that myself). I was hoping someone had additional knowledge not in the doc

Comment: @jntrcs Are you aware of the estimand framework and are you aware that this was a Bayesian study? Estimands relate to intercurrent events, an important feature of this study. The VE has a weird distribution but would be expected to be 0 if the drug was ineffective. $\theta$ has a desired feature that 1/2 means no effect and is bounded from 0 to 1 so amenable to logistic modeling for which beta-binomial modeling is a popular Bayesian modeling choice. Is this all your question is about?